# Changing an identity seed without losing or changing current data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing Database with some values that I do not want to lose/change, however I wish to change the identity seed so dropping the table is out of the question.

Is there any way I can do this without losing my data?

Comment: why would you want to change the identity seed?

Comment: You can change the next value to be handed out, using `DBCC CHECKIDENT()` - but you **cannot** change the identity seed without dropping the column

Comment: you want to change the whole identity colomn values or only for new records ?

Comment: only for new records, I was considering changing the auto increment but I wasn't sure this was the right way to go

Comment: If you care about the numerical values in an IDENTITY column, *you're doing something wrong*. You should treat them as opaque values with *no* inherent meaning.

Comment: with DBCC I would require something like

DBCC CHECKIDENT(table_name [, { RESEED[, 1000000] }])

right?

In response to Damien: The ID's are used to relate various tables to each other and there is no way to change this as the entire system is built like this.

Comment: Looking over it, can someone give me a proper explanation as to what the Reseed will actually do as this looks like it literally just reseeds which would require the column to be dropped.

Comment: Yes, using them as foreign key values is fine. It's caring about *what* numerical value is used that is an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the seed (current value) using [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) with the RESEED option.

Syntax

> DBCC CHECKIDENT (
>       table_name
>           [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ] )
>   [ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]

e.g.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'myTable', RESEED, 1234 )
```

If you mean changing the initial value, such that would apply if you were to do a `TRUNCATE TABLE` - then you cannot without a `DROP`/`CREATE` table sequence or a `DROP`/`ADD` column sequence.